# Calling functions while using multiple .cpp files

Tags: c++, inline, function-call

I would like to ask a question about the output when I called an inline function, that was declared inside `MyHeader.h`, which was defined in both `source_1.cpp` and `source_2.cpp` files, using the `int main()` function inside `source_2.cpp`file.

When I do such a call, the one defined inside the `source_1.cpp` function is called. The codes are like;

My `MyHeader.h` contains the following line of codes:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

inline int func(void);
```

My `source_1.cpp` contains the following line of codes:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

int func(void)
{
    std::cout << "func(), inside source_1, was called. 102 * 102 will be returned." << "\n";
    return 102 * 102;
}

void source_1(void)
{
    std::cout << "source_1() was called. func() will be called." << "\n";
    func();
}
```

My `source_2.cpp` contains the following line of codes:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

int func(void)
{
    std::cout << "func(), inside source_2, was called. 102 * 102 will be returned." << "\n";
    return 102 * 102;
}

void source_2(void)
{
    std::cout << "source_2() was called. func() will be called." << "\n";
    func();
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "main() was called." << "\n";
    source_2();
}
```

This is the output:

```
main() was called.
source_2() was called. func() will be called.
func(), inside source_1, was called. 102*102 will be returned.
```

I wish to know the reason.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's in that picture? Unfortunately I am blind, and my screen reader spells out only gibberish there.

Comment: Here is the text in the picture,
main() was called.
source_2() was called. func() will be called.
func(), inside source_1, was called. 102*102 will be returned.

Comment: Can't you put that text as code formatted in your question please?

Comment: `main() was called. source_2() was called. func() will be called. func(), inside source_1, was called. 102*102 will be returned.` Is it good now?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you remove the image from the question and add the output with code formatting in the question.

Comment: I answered your question. If my answer answers your question, please accept by clicking the tick icon next to my answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You violated the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). You are not permitted to have non-static objects in your program with different implementations. The compiler/linker is free to choose any implementation it finds, which can lead to very hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `source_2` function called `func` function of `source_1.cpp` because `func` is declared as `inline` , not `static` . When the linker gets a `inline` function, it remove all copies of that function except one. So the `func` function of `source_1.cpp` is kept, other one is removed by the linker. If you want to have two separate implementation of one function in two source file, declare the function as `static` . This prevents the linker from removing multiple functions of same name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was kinda busy and will edit the code. Thank you again.

Comment: @AhmetKandemirPEHLİVANLI Please accept my answer if it helps you.